# How to reset Password Using PHP Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, password-recovery

Am working on a Password reset system whereby the user who forgot his password can request for password reset link by submitting his email used in registration. I successfully create the email, it sent the link and I test the link by clicking on it. The link went through and load the reset page but my problem is how to make the system recognise the user who click through and get all the details including Name, Token, email with which the system will confirm that the user is the user who requested the link.

The following is what I have done so far:

Controller

```
    public function preset(){
        $data['success']='';
        $data['error']='';
        include_once ('query/user_query.php');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|valid_email');
         $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<div class='alert alert-warning'><span type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times</span>","</div>");

    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){

        $this->load->view('passwordrecovery.php', $data);
    }
    else{
        $eMail = $this->input->post('email');
         $this->db->where("email = '$eMail'");
        $this->db->from("useraccount");
        $countResult = $this->db->count_all_results();


        if($countResult >=1){
           // $data['firstName'] = '';
          //  $data['lastName'] = '';
            $this->db->where("email = '$eMail'");
            $getUserData =$this->db->get("useraccount")->result();
             foreach($getUserData as $userD){

             $data['firstName'] = $userD->firstname;
             $data['lastName'] = $userD->lastname;
             }
            $sender_email = 'xxx@gmail.com';
            $user_password = 'xxxxxx';
            $token = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 50);
            $subject = 'Password Reset';
            $message = '';
            $message .= "<h2>You are receiving this message in response to your request for password reset</h2>"
                    . "<p>Follow this link to reset your password <a href='".site_url()."/authenticate/resetpassword/.$token' >Reset Password</a> </p>"
                    . "<p>If You did not make this request kindly ignore!</p>"
                    . "<P class='pj'><h2>Kind Regard: Votemate</h2></p>"
                    . "<style>"
                    . ".pj{"
                    . "color:green;"
                    . "}"
                    . "</style>"
                    . "";
            // Configure email library
 $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
 $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
 $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
 $config['smtp_user'] = $sender_email;
 $config['smtp_pass'] = $user_password;
 $config['mailtype'] = 'html';

 // Load email library and passing configured values to email library
 $this->load->library('email', $config);
 //$this->email->set_newline("rn");
 $this->email->set_mailtype("html");

 // Sender email address
 $this->email->from($sender_email);
 // Receiver email address
 $this->email->to($eMail);
// Subject of email
$this->email->subject($subject);
// Message in email
$this->email->message($message);

if ($this->email->send()) {

$eMail = $this->input->post('email');
$ipadd = $this->input->ip_address();
$insert = array(
  'email' => $eMail,
    'ipaddress' => $ipadd,
    'token' => $token
 );

 $this->db->insert('passwordreset', $insert);
 $mail = $this->session->set_userdata('email');
 $data['success'] = 'Email Successfully Send !';
 $this->load->view('linksent.php', $data);
 } else {
 $data['error'] =  '<p class="error_msg">Invalid Gmail Account or Password ! 
  </p>';
 }
 $this->load->view('passwordrecovery.php', $data);
  }


        if($countResult <= 0){

            //user already registered

            $data['error'] = "<div class='alert alert-warning'> Invalid 
    email address<span type='button' class='close' data- 
    dismiss='alert'>&times</span></div>";

            $this->load->view('passwordrecovery.php',$data);

        }

        }


         }
```

View

```
     <div>
                <h1>Password Recovery</h1>
                <h3>Enter your email to receive the password reset link in 
       your Inbox</h3>
                <br/>

                <?php echo form_open('authenticate/preset');?>
                <?php echo $error;?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="email" required="required">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn-success 
      btn" >
                </div>
                <?php echo form_close()?>
     <br/><br/><br/>


            </div>
```

Database: The following is database where I store the info:

```
   CREATE TABLE `passwordreset` (
   `resetid` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
   `ipaddress` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
   `token` varchar(512) NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE
```

The help I need is how to get the details (Name, email, token) of the user who click the link from his email and use it to validate and also use it to update his password. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass user email or token in url or in hidden field when user click on verify link and check in controller method.

```
<a href="<?=site_url('user_verification?user_email=' . $user_email . '&user_code=' .  $user_code);?> Click To Verifiy Email </a>
```

user_verification controller

```
public function user_verification_get()
{
   $user_email = $this->input->get('user_email');
   $user_code = $this->input->get('user_code');

   $data=$this->admin_model->user_verification($user_email,$user_code);

   if($data)
    {
        $data['message'] = 'Success.';
    }
    else
    {
        $data['message'] = 'Not Valid User.';
    }
    $this->load->template('verify', $data);
}
```

Model

```
public function user_verification($user_email,$user_code){

    $this->db->select('user_email');
    $this->db->where('user_email',$user_email);
    $this->db->where('user_code',$user_code);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if($query->row_array() > 0)
    {
        $data['user_isactive'] = true;

        $this->db->where('user_email',$user_email);
        $this->db->update('users',$data);
        return $query->row_array();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: when you call view pass user_email and code or token.

Comment: Your contribution realy inspired me. I later figured it out.  I added $token as a parameter for the function through which am able to get the value of the token which I use to check the database if the token is correct or not before password reset                                                                          
          public function resetpassword($token)

Comment: I voted up your answer but I don't how to accept the answer can you put me through.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a database table to store the tokens. Before sending the email, You must generate a unique token and add it into a separate table. The password reset link must contain encoded token and userID. Once the password reset link is clicked, you must check the encoded token and UserID in the link matches to the entry in database? If yes, then show the change password page, If not, you must show a message "Link is expired" or whatever.

Here is the hint of code from my project.

```
$act_code = md5(rand(0,1000).'uniquefrasehere');
$activate['UserID']  $USERID;
$activate['TokenNumber'] = $act_code;
$activate['UserEmail'] = $email;
$activate['TokenTime'] = time();
$str_tmp = $this->db->insert_string('forgetpasswordtoken', $activate);
$query_tmp = $this->db->query($str_tmp);
```

Once the link is clicked, You must check using the following code:

```
$record = $this->user_model->checkforgot($uid[0], base64_decode($uid[1]));
if($record == true){
    $data['uid'] = $uid[1];
}
else
{
    $msg = "You have already changed your password or your link was expired.!";
}
```

And What the checkforgotpassword function does? Here is below:

```
function checkforgot($token, $id)
{
    $qry = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM forgetpasswordtoken WHERE TokenNumber = '".$token."' AND UserID = $id");
    $num_row = $qry->num_rows();
    if($num_row!=0)
    {
        $del = $this->db->delete('forgetpasswordtoken', array('TokenNumber' => $token, 'UserID' => $id)); 
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can further add the time limit of few hours before the link expires.
Let me know after adding this in your project.

Thanks,

Comment: I appreciate your support. I already have a database table where I store the details. After the link is clicked, how am I going to get the data with which I will compare with the data in the database? I hope you get the picture right?